# How to convert excel rate() formula into step by step formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to convert this excel rate() formula `=RATE(D5,-D8,D3,,D6)*12` into manual formula for me to get the Effective Rate.
[image: Excel formula Screenshot]
How can I convert this rate() `=RATE(D5,-D8,D3,,D6)*12` formula from excel into a step by step formula?
The Effective Rate formula that I found online has not been able to reproduce the same results from the excel file.

You can download the excel file from [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mqZdLKBlMqtu3aLYk2RRtsaApSjmjocw/view?usp=sharing)
Appreciate if anyone  can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a closed-form formula for the effective interest of an amortized loan payment. The [`RATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rate-function-9f665657-4a7e-4bb7-a030-83fc59e748ce) formula in Excel uses an iterative approach to "solve" for the rate by guessing and adjusting the rate until the present value of the payments matches the passed-in PV.

Comment: Can you provide 3-5 code example how can we calculate Effective Rate in programming? Preferably in PHP but in other languages is also fine.

Comment: I won't write code for you, but look for the formula for PV of a loan, and how to find solutions iteratively using "root finding" algorithms.